# Have to create an array of objects for different tools to do undo/redo operations using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
for circle tool    
 var circle_array = {"object_Name":"circle", "object_ID":"" , "start_x":"mouse.x" , "start_y":"mouse.y", "start_radius":"mouse.x" };
        var onCirclePaint = function () {
            // Tmp canvas is always cleared up before drawing.
            tmp_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_canvas.width, tmp_canvas.height);

            var x = (mouse.x + start_mouse.x) / 2;
            var y = (mouse.y + start_mouse.y) / 2;

            var radius = Math.max(
                Math.abs(mouse.x - start_mouse.x),
                Math.abs(mouse.y - start_mouse.y)) / 2;

            tmp_ctx.beginPath();
            tmp_ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            // tmp_ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
            tmp_ctx.strokeStyle = $('#selColor').val();
            tmp_ctx.lineWidth = $('#selWidth').val();
            tmp_ctx.stroke();
            tmp_ctx.closePath();

                    circle_array.start_x = mouse.x;
                    circle_array.start_y = mouse.y;
                    circle_array.start_radius = mouse.x;
        };

for line tool
                var line_Array = {"object_Name":"Line", "object_ID":"", "start_x":"start_mouse.x", "start_y":"start_mouse.y", "end_x":"mouse.x", "end_y":"mouse.y"};
                var onLinePaint = function () {
            tmp_ctx.lineWidth = $('#selWidth').val();
            tmp_ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
            tmp_ctx.lineCap = 'round';
            tmp_ctx.strokeStyle = $('#selColor').val();
            tmp_ctx.fillStyle = $('#selColor').val();
            // Tmp canvas is always cleared up before drawing.
            tmp_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_canvas.width, tmp_canvas.height);

            tmp_ctx.beginPath();
            tmp_ctx.moveTo(start_mouse.x, start_mouse.y);
            tmp_ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
            tmp_ctx.stroke();
            tmp_ctx.closePath();

            //                line_Array.object_ID =start_mouse.y;
                    line_Array.start_x =start_mouse.x;
                    line_Array.start_y =start_mouse.y;
                    line_Array.end_x = mouse.x;
                    line_Array.end_y = mouse.y;
                    console.log('this :'+start_mouse.x);
        };

for rectangle tool
            var Rectangle_Array = {"object_Name":"Rectangle", "object_ID":"", "start_x":"mouse.x", "start_y":"mouse.y", "start_width":"mouse.x", "start_height":"mouse.y" };
            var onRectPaint = function () {
            tmp_ctx.lineWidth = $('#selWidth').val();
            tmp_ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
            tmp_ctx.lineCap = 'round';
            tmp_ctx.strokeStyle = $('#selColor').val();
            tmp_ctx.fillStyle = $('#selColor').val();
            // Tmp canvas is always cleared up before drawing.
            tmp_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_canvas.width, tmp_canvas.height);

            var x = Math.min(mouse.x, start_mouse.x);
                    var y = Math.min(mouse.y, start_mouse.y);
            var width = Math.abs(mouse.x - start_mouse.x);
            var height = Math.abs(mouse.y - start_mouse.y);
            tmp_ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);

                    Rectangle_Array.start_x =mouse.x;
                    Rectangle_Array.start_y =mouse.y;
                    Rectangle_Array.start_width = mouse.x;
                    Rectangle_Array.start_height = mouse.y;

                    console.log('this :'+mouse.x);
        };
```

i created an array for each tool but i need to create an array of objects and do the undo/redo functions using push pop method for above code .please someone help me.
i created an array for each tool but i need to create an array of objects and do the undo/redo functions using push pop method for above code .please someone help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an arraylist for undo/redo for my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539332/create-an-arraylist-for-undo-redo-for-my-code)

Comment: yes please help me for this code

Comment: please help me Mr.Jaromanda X sir

Comment: I just marked this a duplicate of your question yesterday, not about to help

Comment: How is this different to [your question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539332/create-an-arraylist-for-undo-redo-for-my-code)?

Comment: please check link provided in upper comment if it solve your problem please close the thread or again ask for help

Comment: same question only but i added to two more tools

Comment: your arrays are objects not arrays!

Comment: how to change that objects into arrays ? someone help me